# twitter bootstrap href button does not work

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am creating a html template for a django based app. I am using the twitter bootstrap API for buttons here, but one of them (the cancel button) doesn't seem to be working correctly. I link it to another page using an href, but when I click on the button, it redirects to the current page's post method. See below:

```
<h2>Add new Schedule:</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" method='post'>
<table>
{% load bootstrap %}
{{ form|bootstrap }}
{% csrf_token %}
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' name='reset' value='Save' />
</td>
<td></td>
<td><a href='{%url head.views.edit_instance_binding binding.id %}'><button class="btn     btn-inverse" type="submit">Cancel</button></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

However, if I get rid of the button and use it as a simple href it seems to work:
    `<td><a href='{%url head.views.edit_instance_binding binding.id %}'>Cancel</a></td>`

What's going on here?

Comment: Why not try putting the btn class on the hyperlink it self rather than placing a submit button inside of a hyperlink?

Comment: yup that worked, I thought you could only use a button class if you use a button tag (I'm new to webdev)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a `<button>` inside an `<a>` element - get rid of the button, otherwise you'll be submitting your form.

If you want your anchor to be styled as a button, give it a `btn` class.

And Bootstrap is just a big set of CSS facilities with little js thrown in - no APIs at all :))

EDIT: nowadays HTML semantics and appearance are well separated [though someone may argue that Bootstrap has its hacks regarding this, see its `<i>`'s use for icons].

Keeping the eye on your case, you wanted to use a `<button>` to style a simple anchor like an embossed button. But a `<button>` tag is just a way to provide a richer `<input type="submit">`, in which you can insert images for example [see all the BS examples with icons beside buttons].

Well, `<input type="submit">` and `<button>` inside a `<form>` trigger the latter's `action`, i.e. they post some data the user entered to such location.

If you just need to reach some URL without submitting anything, you need an anchor tag [`<a>`], which can be styled as you wish, e.g. with BS `btn`, `btn-primary`, `btn-whateva` classes.

Comment: that worked perfectly :) I am new to bootstrap and webdev in general, so I was wondering if you could explain why it doesn't work the way I did it (just for my knowledge). Thanks :)